# Polar plot for $\frac{j\omega}{1 + j\omega \tau}$

Tags: polar-coordinates, control-theory, stability-theory

Okay I'm from electrical engineering background and we represent imaginary number as $j$. I'm supposed to draw polar plot for transfer function given as
$$F(j\omega) = \frac{j\omega}{1 + j\omega \tau}$$
as $\omega$ varies from zero to infinity, and $\tau$ is constant. I tried calculating magnitude and phase for $\omega = 0$, which both comes out to be zero. Was I right? And I'm having lots of trouble calculating it for $\omega = \infty$, can anyone guide me pls.

Comment: It's called a transfer function because it's derived using Fourier transforms. You're obviously not expected to know this at this level, but it's nice to know they're using real terminology.

Comment: Ohhh I see, thanks for this info! My book said just replace s by jW.. we're doing steady-state analysis right now, I guess that Fourier thing plays part during transient response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking at large $\omega$, just divide both numerator and denominator by $j\omega$. What you get is $$F(j\omega)=\frac{1}{\tau+\frac{1}{j\omega}}$$
For large $\omega$, the $1/(j\omega)$ part goes to zero (imaginary 0, but still 0). So $$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty}F(j\omega)=\frac{1}{\tau}$$

In general, you can write $$F(j\omega)=\frac{j\omega}{1+j\omega\tau}=\frac{j\omega(1-j\omega\tau)}{(1+j\omega\tau)(1-j\omega\tau)}\\=\frac{\omega^2\tau+j\omega}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}\\=\frac{\omega^2\tau}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}+j\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}$$
The magnitude is then $$|F(j\omega)|=\frac{\omega\sqrt{1+\omega^2\tau^2}}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}=\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2\tau^2}}$$
The phase is given by $$\tan\psi=\frac{\omega}{\omega^2\tau}=\frac{1}{\omega\tau}$$

Comment: Can you pls expand your answer to include both magnitude and phase for w=0 and w=infinity. Because this way I guess what I've found for w = 0 is also wrong & also hint me about nature of graph if that's not too much ^^"

Comment: Ohk, I think without any manipulation its clear that F(j0) = 0, so I guess I can't use same formula for finding magnitude in both case, am I on right track?